# Display multiple columns in a group header with charts

Tags: crystal-reports

I want charts generated for each group to appear in a multi-column format in one group header. I could do it with subreports, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to load the data set multiple times. How can I achieve this?

[image: Multiple charts in one group header]

Comment: Will there always be 6 groups? I have a hard time seeing how you'd do this without subreports, especially if that number can vary.

Comment: The number of groups will vary. I couldn't think of a way to do it without subreports either. I was hoping someone here may have further insight.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, Crystal isn't a good fit for this.

Even if the number of groups *wasn't* variable, Crystal reports is fixated on delivering and iterating your records from top to bottom. It's not *impossible* to structure that, but it would be way more work than it's worth. Plus you'd waste too much time handling the variable number of charts and ensuring unused ones were suppressed. And even then, you'd probably need to use subreports.

---

You'd have better luck using something *other* than Crystal for generating this behavior. Even if it meant creating a subreport for the chart and writing a VS program that displayed that report multiple times for each "Group".

Comment: Thanks for the input and suggestions.  I'll just report it the way Crystal wants. :(

Comment: @ParleyKennelly It's the price we pay for using legacy products from 1991. You might look into reporting alternatives, or develop the desired behavior in your main program rather than a standalone report.